# how to recover archived emails in another account?

Tags: email, outlook

The problem is：
I used to have a xxx@shaw.ca accounts and have some important emails stored locally using Outlook. Right now, I am switching to another ISP, which means I can't access the old email server any more. Can I restore my old emails into another account（like gmail) or just let them show in the outlook UI?

THANK YOU for any help or hints.

Answer (score 0):

If your new ISP gives you IMAP access you can easily move your email.

If you haven't yet done, configure an account with IMAP. How to do that depends on your ISP.

For gmail you should follow [this Google guide](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en).

Suppose your new ISP is Gmail.

Once you've done that, you would probably create a new folder to store your emails.

You can now select all your local emails that you want to copy/move and drag&drop into your newly folder.

Wait until it finish the copy (time depends on how fast is your connection and how `heavy` are all your emails).

You're done!